# How to align view to right of the screen in Android?

Tags: android

How to align view to right of the screen in Android ?

i have used

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/heading" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/widget30" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/logo_cpw">
    </ImageView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/widget28" android:layout_width="134px"
        android:layout_height="35px" android:text="EditText"
        android:textSize="18sp" android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text_effects"
        android:gravity="right" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </EditText>


</LinearLayout>
```

But it is not aligning to the right ? any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing LinearLayout with RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/widget30" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/logo_cpw">
    </ImageView>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/widget28" android:layout_width="134px"
            android:layout_height="35px" android:text="EditText"
            android:textSize="18sp" android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text_effects"
            android:gravity="right" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        </EditText>


</LinearLayout>
```

Used this but not worked

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a gravity element in the base LinearLayout.  This will align all the child elements of the container (the main LinearLayout) to the right.

Like this (last attribute):

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/heading" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right">
```